# Does Sparrow for iOS seamlessly integrate with Gmail's Send As feature?

Tags: gmail, email

I just saw [this blog post about Sparrow](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/app-review-sparrow-for-iphone/), and I was wondering about one of its features. On [the website](http://sparrowmailapp.com/iphone.php), it says that it has the following feature:

> **Quick sender switch -** switch sender account by tapping the top bar when composing a message.

I'm wondering if this automatically integrates with [Gmail's Send As feature](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370) or not. For example, say I have 10 accounts already set up in my Gmail account so that I can send mail as them, do I need to manually enter all the credentials for these 10 accounts in Sparrow? Or does it automatically detect these additional "send as" accounts and let me use them?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Sparrow allows you to add "aliases" to each account so you can, from one account, send mail as a different user that's been registered as a send-as user in your Gmail account.

You click on the Preferences icon in the account view screen. Then click on the specific account. And then click on the 'Aliases' menu option to add new alises.

From one of my accounts I send mail as either me or my business account (which happens to be set at my business ISP to forward in to my Gmail account):

[image: Sparrow iOS: Aliases]

From the new mail composition window you click on the top bar to change who you're sending the email as and then you pick the account from the list Sparrow shows you:

[image: Sparrow iOS: Chose send-as user]

[image: Sparrow iOS: The list to pick send-as user from]

It works the same way in Sparrow on OS X for what it's worth:

[image: Sparrow OS X: Aliases]

Comment: So when you choose to add an alias, it presents you with the list of--for example 10--"Send as" accounts you already have set up in Gmail? (i.e. you don't need to retype them or enter in their credentials?)

Comment: You can enter anything you want. It doesn't show you a list. And you don't need to enter any credentials, you've already set the credds up for the primary account under which you're adding the alias. If you give it an alias that you don't have permission to use in Gmail account already, sending via the alias will just fail.

Comment: For that reason Sparrow is still the best email client by miles and light years. Thanks for clarifying this.